# Stopping Wordpress From Appending /index.html to everything

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a spaghetti code of a theme I inherited from someone and for whatever reason Google Analytics shows that I keep getting hits to a variety of URLs on the site, but the urls are all appended with /index.html.  So an example would be like http://www.mysite.com/category/storyname/index.html

And it appears to be doing this to almost everything (despite my permalinks being set to be "tidy").

So...

1. What in the hell could be possibly causing this?
2. How do I fix it?  When I visit all those pages I get 404 errors so that means my visitors are not getting what they want.

I have the Redirection plugin and have been manually trying to update some of these, but it is ridiculous.  I'm sure there's a way to do it with htaccess but I know next to nothing about that.  Here's what my htaccess currently has (the default):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Where does index.html turn up? In the links, or when entering a link?

Comment: Are there any foreign plugins installed? Wouldn't be surprised if there was an SEO plugin installed at one point, or perhaps a cacheing plugin. See if one still is, perhaps. If not, maybe one configured a bunch of permalinks ending on .html in the past and left the configuration behind.

Answer (score 1):

Something tells me this might be the result of a spider crawling your site trying to guess at your URLs. Can you post of of the logs that show the pages? Are you getting lots of requests for this in a row, from the same user agent?

If I'm right you really can't do anything about it except you could code a redirect for each of them, which is pretty easy to do if you can handle PHP.  This answer over on WordPress Answers explains how:

- [**Creating 301 Redirects for Post, Page, Category and Image URLs?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/creating-301-redirects-for-post-page-category-and-image-urls/1023#1023)

Hope this helps.

-Mike